# Inequality of $L^p \left ( \mathbb{R} \right )$ norms of functions and their derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove that there is a constant $\space C>0 \space$ such that for any function $\space u \in C^{\infty}_{0} \left ( \mathbb{R} \right ) \space$ following inequality holds:

${\left \| u \right \|}_{L^2 \left ( \mathbb{R} \right )} \leq C {\left \| u' \right \|}^{1/2}_{L^1 \left ( \mathbb{R} \right )} {\left \| u \right \|}^{1/2}_{L^1 \left ( \mathbb{R} \right )}$

I'm actually trying to get much stronger result, but I don't even know how to prove this one.

I was thinking about using the fundamental theorem of calculus and Hölder's inequality, but I don't know how exactly.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular case of the [Gagliardo-Niremberg inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality) with (notation as in the Wikipedia article)
$$
n=1,\quad j=0,\quad p=2,\quad r=q=1,\quad \alpha=\frac12.
$$

Comment: OK, I see, thank you. Do you know where I could find a proof of the inequality?